# Azure Speech SDK Speech-to-Text to Stream Audio Segments

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have been working with Azure's Speech-To-Text service found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-csharp#recognize-from-file), using the recognize from in-memory stream method. Essentially what I plan to do is stream only certain segments of the audio to the services, but I am not entirely sure on how to do so. Say I have a video of length 5 minutes and my goal is to only stream the first 30 seconds or even just from the 1 minute mark to the 3 minute mark in the audio file, what would I need to enable or change in the following code to do so?

I have attempted to use CreatePullStream() instead of CreatePushStream() providing the mark in seconds, but it did not produce the goal that I have described above. If anyone knows, please let me know how I can achieve this, much thanks!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

class Program 
{
    async static Task FromStream(SpeechConfig speechConfig)
    {
        var reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("audioFile.wav"));
        using var audioInputStream = AudioInputStream.CreatePushStream();
        using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(audioInputStream);
        using var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

        byte[] readBytes;
        do
        {
            readBytes = reader.ReadBytes(1024);
            audioInputStream.Write(readBytes, readBytes.Length);
        } while (readBytes.Length > 0);

        var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={result.Text}");
    }

    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("<paste-your-subscription-key>", "<paste-your-region>");
        await FromStream(speechConfig);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `NAudio.Wave` to cut your source .wav files. For instance, if you want to recognize 1min - 3 min content of a .wav file, try code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using NAudio.Wave;

class Program
{
    async static Task FromStream(SpeechConfig speechConfig)
    {

        var inputAudioPath = @"<path>";
        var outputAudioPath = @"<path>";
        var startAt = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0); //start at 1 min
        var duration = new TimeSpan(0,2,0); //cut 1-3 min audio, it lasts 2 mins

        CutAudio(inputAudioPath, outputAudioPath, startAt, duration);

        var reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(outputAudioPath));
        var audioInputStream = AudioInputStream.CreatePushStream();
        var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(audioInputStream);
        var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

        byte[] readBytes;
        do
        {
            readBytes = reader.ReadBytes(1024);
            audioInputStream.Write(readBytes, readBytes.Length);
        } while (readBytes.Length > 0);

        var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={result.Text}");
    }


    public static void CutAudio(String inputPath,String destPath,TimeSpan startAt, TimeSpan duration) {

        using (var reader = new AudioFileReader(inputPath))
        {
            reader.CurrentTime = startAt; // jump forward to the position we want to start from
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(destPath, reader.Take(duration));
        }
    }


    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {


        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("<key>", "<region>");
        await FromStream(speechConfig);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Btw, if you want to recognize long audios, pls see [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-csharp#continuous-recognition) and my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969499/how-to-return-a-simple-timestamp-output-in-azure/66980651#66980651).

Comment: Is there a way to implement this method without having to create a new audio file every time? I understand the method that you have implemented here and it is definitely one of the ways to do so but I simply just want to stream certain segments of the audio file to the Speech-To-Text service. Because let's say in addition to streaming from the 1 minute mark to the three minute mark, I plan to also stream the final 30 seconds of the audio file as well. I feel it would be better just providing the specific intervals that I want to send in. @Stanley

Comment: @AfricanMamba, sorry, not sure about it, I am using this way in my project: creating required .wav files and remove them after use.

Comment: @AfricanMamba, how's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately, my issue has not been resolved. I appreciate your help, but I need to find a way to implement the method without having to produce new audio files or manipulating it. I have been searching for how to stream only portions of the audio, but I have not yet discovered it. Thank you for checking in.